# Where are the header files for C in Xcode?

Tags: header-files

I'm trying to find the header files for things such as limits.h in XCode.  Where do they exist?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your target SDK. Usually, you will find them in

```
/Developer/SDKs/<insert SDK here>/usr/include
```

For example,

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/include
```

Answer (score 1):

- /usr/include/limits.h on my machine

That (/usr/include) is the normal place place for system headers on Unix-based machines.  Sometimes, extensions have their code (headers, libraries) placed under /usr/local instead (/usr/local/include for headers, /usr/local/lib for libraries).